# Comparion True If Null Or Empty String

Tags: javascript

I have a value in my app's state that is used to set the value of a form input field. At any given point, this value can be null, undefined, an empty string, or a string.

I then have a function, that tests to see if the prev value of the variable is not equal to the current value:

```
checkValues(prevValue, curValue) {
    if(prevValue != curValue && !curValue) { // do something }
}
```

The problem is, if prevValue was an empty string, and curValue is null, it always does the thing. This happens sometimes in instances where data was fetched from an API. The value that was initially set to empty string becomes null:

```
if('' != null) { // it does the thing because they are not the same }
```

However, I DON'T want to do the thing in this situation. How can I allow '' != null to return false instead of true?

Comment: you get always `false` for different values.

Comment: I need the !comparison to return false if one is null and one is an empty string

Comment: please add the cases and the wanted results to the question.

Comment: you have to write a function that explicitly checks for that there is no built in operator

Comment: `(prevValue + currValue !== "null" && prevValue != currValue)`

Comment: But I actually think this is an XY question? Whats your exact usecase? Why do you need that comparison at all?

Comment: I have a form input value, that could either be null or an empty string or a real string, and I want something to happen if the prev value does not equal the cur value. But the problem is when the value changes from empty string to null, it passes, and runs the code. I don't want that to happen.

Comment: Voíla, thats your *real problem* ... and you got an answer to it one minute before you asked it :)

Comment: a form input can never be `null`.

Comment: @NinaScholz The value of the variable i use to populate the value of the input can be null though.

Comment: I have updated my question to be more explicit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a double pipe operator (`||`) to force `null` or `undefined` values to empty strings:

```js
if ((prevValue || '') != (curValue || '')) {
}
```

You could make it cleaner by separating those double pipe operations from the `if` such as:

```js
var left = prevValue || '';
var right = curValue || '';
if (left != right) {
}
```

Comment: double pipe is not the real terminus, but [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR).

Comment: I know. It's often referred to as "double pipe operator", so I use that and "logical OR" interchangeably. Perfectly fine point to make, of course. :D